# Callback, observers, and asynch sockets in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, sockets, network-programming

I'm still a neophyte Python programmer and I'm trying to do something that is a bit over my head.

What I've done is create a simple IRC bot using asyncore (and asynchronous sockets module).  The client runs in a continuous loop, listening to the conversation in the channel.  What I would like to do (I think?) is implement an observer pattern so I can respond to events.  I imagine it would look somthing like this:

```
class MyBot(object):

   def __init__(self):
      bot = MyIRCClient(server='whatever', channel='#whatever')
      bot.observe(event='join', handler='log_join')
      bot.connect() # Bot is now listening continously in a loop

   def log_join(self, e):
      print e + ' joined the channel.'
```

I'm basing this design around what I know of observers used in the various Javascript frameworks.  I don't know if the same technique can or should be applied here.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `Observer` is not a particularly popular DP (design pattern) in Python, it's not a totally "alien" one either, so if you're familiar with it, go right ahead.  However, the normal way to call `observe` would be with `handler=self.log_join`, a callback that's actually a callable, **not** with a string value forcing the `bot` to perform introspection to find out what it actually has to call when the event occurs (and not even giving it a `self` to refer to the object it's supposed to perform introspection on -- shudder!).

`Callback` is a perfectly reasonable and popular DP in Python, but that's because passing around first-class callables (functions, bound methods, classes, instances of classes with a `__call__` method, etc, etc) is so wonderfully easy (pretty trivial, actually;-).